# Hide Base on select (multiple)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to hide and show input just closest select

```js
script
$(function() {
  var inputToHide = $('div[id=other]');
  $('#showhide]').on('change', function() {
    var selected = $('#other option:selected').val();
    if (selected === "other") {
      $(this).closest('div[id=other]').show();
    } else {
      $(this).closest('div[id=other]').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group">
  <span><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></span>
  <select name="web" class="form-control" id="showhide">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select ...</option>
    <option value="car">car</option>
    <option value="train">train</option>
    <option value="other">other</option>
  </select>
</div>

Hide this if not "other" selected
<div class="input-group" id="other">
  <span><i class="fa fa-play"></i></span>
  <input type="text" name="other" class="form-control" />
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="input-group">
  <span><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></span>
  <select name="web" class="form-control" id="showhide">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select ...</option>
    <option value="car">car</option>
    <option value="train">train</option>
    <option value="other">other</option>
  </select>
</div>

Hide this if not "other" selected
<div class="input-group" id="other">
  <span><i class="fa fa-play"></i></span>
  <input type="text" name="other" class="form-control" />
</div>
end html
```

How to do this?

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a lot of incoherences when I reviewed your code.

You use the same id multiple times. You should, at all cost, always try to avoid that! [read here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really)

Also, I was not sure what you were aiming to do. Was it to show the input when the selected option is other? Your code was a little confusing about that.

So I fixed the problems, and acted as you wanted the input to be shown if the selected option was "Other". (note that inputs are hidden on startup, instead of shown)

The code :

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></span>
  <select name="web" class="form-control showhide">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select ...</option>
    <option value="car">car</option>
    <option value="train">train</option>
    <option value="other">other</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="input-group other">
  <span><i class="fa fa-play"></i></span>
  <input type="text" name="other" class="form-control" />
</div>

<br>

<div class="input-group">
  <span><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></span>
  <select name="web" class="form-control showhide">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select ...</option>
    <option value="car">car</option>
    <option value="train">train</option>
    <option value="other">other</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="input-group other">
  <span><i class="fa fa-play"></i></span>
  <input type="text" name="other" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

html

```
$(function() {
  $('.other').hide();
  $('.showhide').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    if (selected === "other") {
      $(this).parent().next(".other").show();
    } else {
      $(this).parent().next(".other").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

js

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8f6z61to/)

Comment: I think if we use parent and next methods if he changes the structure in future then it may problem.

Comment: yes his structure isn't really optimum, i'll give you that. the parent().next() is pretty messy and may break if he changes structure too much.

Comment: check my answer. is that a optimal solution?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
   $('.other').hide();
      $('.showhide').on('change', function() {
   if ($(this).val() == "other") {
          $(this).closest('.section').find('.other').show();
        } else {
          $(this).closest('.section').find('.other').hide();
        }
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></span>
    <select name="web" class="form-control showhide">
   <option value="" selected="selected">Select ...</option>
   <option value="car">car</option>
   <option value="train">train</option>
   <option value="other">other</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group other">
    <span><i class="fa fa-play"></i></span>
    <input type="text" name="other" class="form-control" placeholder="first input"/>
  </div>
 </div>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <div class="section">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></span>
    <select name="web" class="form-control showhide">
   <option value="" selected="selected">Select ...</option>
   <option value="car">car</option>
   <option value="train">train</option>
   <option value="other">other</option>
    </select>
  </div>
      <div class="input-group other">
    <span><i class="fa fa-play"></i></span>
    <input type="text" name="other" class="form-control" placeholder="second input" />
  </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you can change the container class name in the above code. actually structure should be two child divs should be in one parent div with same class name

Comment: i try your answer, but not work.

can you demo your sollution. Thanks

Comment: I updated the code. you can take a look at that. I dont know how to insert working demo here

Comment: Thanks for sollution demo

Answer (score 0):

First i can see that you have identifiers problem, you should use unique `id`s in same document, when you solve that you can improve your script to be like following example and it will work.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$(function() {
    $('body').on('change', '#showhide', function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "other")
            $('#other').show();
        else
            $('#other').hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
  <span><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></span>
  <select name="web" class="form-control" id="showhide">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select ...</option>
    <option value="car">car</option>
    <option value="train">train</option>
    <option value="other">other</option>
  </select>
</div>

Hide this if not "other" selected
<div class="input-group" id="other">
  <span><i class="fa fa-play"></i></span>
  <input type="text" name="other" class="form-control" />
</div>
```